# How to get the image from uiwebview in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, uiimageview, nsurl

here i loaded the content as well as the images in the webview, i want to take the image from the webview and load it into the imageview.

the url of the image is received but the image is not loaded it in to the imageview

here i use the code for taking the image from webview is

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    //Touch gestures below top bar should not make the page turn.
    //EDITED Check for only Tap here instead.
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

        NSUserDefaults * userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        bool pageFlag = [userDefaults boolForKey:@"pageDirectionRTLFlag"];
        NSLog(@"pageFlag tapbtnRight %d", pageFlag);

        if(self.interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait||self.interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
  NSString *imgURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f).src", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y];
            NSString *urlToSave = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:imgURL];
            NSLog(@"urlToSave :%@",urlToSave);
}
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check this out.

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
NSLog(@"TAPPED");
//Touch gestures below top bar should not make the page turn.
//EDITED Check for only Tap here instead.
if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    NSUserDefaults * userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    bool pageFlag = [userDefaults boolForKey:@"pageDirectionRTLFlag"];
    NSLog(@"pageFlag tapbtnRight %d", pageFlag);

    if(self.interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait||self.interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        NSString *imgURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f).src", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y];
        NSString *urlToSave = [webV stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:imgURL];
        NSLog(@"urlToSave :%@",urlToSave);
        NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlToSave];
        NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
        UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        imgView.image = image;//imgView is the reference of UIImageView
    }
  }
return YES;
}
```

Sample code:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/51367042/ImageFromWebView.zip

Comment: @PsychoDad did you figure out how to make it work for google images?

Comment: I tell the user to tap the view image button. From there it works fine.

Comment: I think the OP wants to get the image directly from the loaded `UIWebView`, instead of downloading it again