# how to get image url from an epub file

Tags: ios, epub

I have created an app to read ePub files as @Euan's post

[Reading ePub format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388467/reading-epub-format)

Epub files may contains image as well as text. Images are look like icon. I want to show the images in maximized manner when we tap the image in the ePub file. how can i do this. Help me

Thanks in advance.

Have a nice day.

Comment: Hi guys, I got answer to my query from the below post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703071/how-to-get-the-image-from-uiwebview-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

When you load the html files in your web view make sure that you set the base URL correctly using either `loadHTMLString:baseURL:` or `loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:`. Then webview should load the images normally.

If you want to maximize them when the user taps, the easiest way would be something like this:

- inject jQuery into your EPUB html in `webViewDidFinishLoad:`
- add an action to all `<img>` tags using jQuery which calls a cocoa method using a custom url protocol like `my-epub-app://maximize-img/cool-photo.jpg`
- catch and handle this custom protocol in your `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` and return `NO` to prevent webview from trying to load your invalid URL.

Hope this helps…

Comment: Thanks @enguin. Though i hav got answer, i will try yours also